# Node Curely Brace Require Breaks Cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, cron

I have created a node script that I want to schedule with root's cron. The crontab entry is listed below.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 1 * * * (time node /home/user/test/index.js) > /tmp/dbbackup 2>&1
```

I can run the exact same command without error as regular user or root. However, when executed from the scheduler, it breaks immediately with a syntax error

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3
```

I read something yesterday (that I'm having trouble linking back to now) about not running an adequate version of Node, but after updating am still seeing the same results.

```
 node --version
v12.19.0
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `node` which `root` runs the same version? i.e. `sudo su -` and `node --version`? Since you're scheduling it in root's crontab, `node` will be ran with whichever `node` the root user has in its PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The `node --version` above was executed by root. Both regular use and root are updated to `v12.19.0` and are executing the script from a terminal without error. I'm wondering if my cron declaration `SHELL=/bin/bash` might be doing something? But that's the only way I could figure to wrap my time command.

Comment: Well, you can try moving `time node /path/index.js` into a script under /root/ and invoking that script instead. Inside that script, you could also run `node --version` and `which node` and output them somewhere to help you see if it is about the node version.

Comment: Thank again! The solution was a combination of `which node` and `whereis node`. Apparently I had `v4.8.2` installed to `/usr/bin/node` and `v12.19.0` installed to `/usr/local/bin/node`. After realizing this, I just specify which version I want to call in my cron.

Comment: Great! Be sure to add that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a combination of `which node` and `whereis node`. Apparently I had v4.8.2 installed to /usr/bin/node and v12.19.0 installed to /usr/local/bin/node. After realizing this, I just specify which version I want to call in my cron.